# intellij source code does not match bytecode when debugging

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, bytecode

intellij: source code does not match bytecode when debugging. The source code is a dependency source code, and has lots of compile error: can not resolve symbols.

When showing diff, the only diff are symbols, comments and imports. Decompiled code is supposed to be different from source code.

The source code is the latest code, and its jar is built from the latest source code.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Have you connected the source code as a source code dependency in Porject settings -> Dependencies? Is it possible to share a sample project?